# Access denied when running phinx command on Docker container

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose, phinx

I am running the official MySQL Docker container for my PHP app.  I am using Phinx for migrations.  The MySQL image seems to work fine as I can connect to it as 'dbuser' (non-root) using MySQL Workbench.  I can also connect with Docker exec as well.

Problem occurs when I try to run any Phinx command, such as status.  I'm getting:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
There was a problem connecting to the database: SQLSTATE[HY000][1045] Access denied for user 'dbuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

My grants on the DB look like:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'dbuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*8232A1298A49F710DBEE0B330C42EEC825D4190A'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `dbuser`.* TO 'app_db'@'%'
```

My `development` section of the phinx.yml file looks like:

```
development:
    adapter: mysql
    host: localhost
    name: app_db
    user: dbuser
    pass: '<no-hash-password>'
    port: 3306
    charset: utf8
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why did you type '*8232A1298A49F710DBEE0B330C42EEC825D4190A' instead of '8232A1298A49F710DBEE0B330C42EEC825D4190A' ? Why the additional asterisk?

Comment: That's literally what was displayed

Comment: anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it:  I had MySQL running on the host as well (different port 3307), so I shut that down.  I'm now able to run `phinx` within the container.  Looks like it might have been trying to connect to the host server via unix socket, instead of port 3306 on the container.